# Is $(\Box \nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\Box)\phi=0$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, differentiation

In Eq. 15 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0819 the author has a term that looks like $(\Box \nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\Box)\phi$. Since for a scalar quantity $\nabla_\nu\phi = \partial _\nu\phi$ and $\Box\phi$ is a scalar, I would expect $(\Box \nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\Box)\phi=0$.

But the author has this term equal to something. Can anyone explain why this term is not set to zero? Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

(In $f(R)$ gravity, $\frac{df}{dR}$ is often treated as a scalar field.)

Comment: Thinking about it some more, maybe this is zero, but the author did not explicitly set this term to zero to demonstrate that the first term and last term in Eq. 14 cancel, to allow us to reach Eq. 16.

Comment: It cannot be 0, think about it. The box is two times covariant derivative. Apply one of them to a scalar and you get a 4-vector. Apply it the second time, and it's already complicated.

Comment: Are you saying $\Box\phi$ is not a scalar?
And if so, how do we then arrive at Eq. 16 in the paper mentioned?

Comment: $\square \phi$ is a scalar, yes, but you're trying to move a derivative through the box, and so you shouldn't think of $\square \phi$ as a single indivisible entity. You would be right to conclude
$$ \nabla_\mu \nabla _\nu \square \phi = \nabla_\nu \nabla_\mu \square \phi \,,$$
for instance.

Comment: I am willing to expand the operators and check it. Are you?

Comment: Would it be correct to say that Eq. 15  comes about from finding the vacuum solution to $\nabla^\mu\mathcal{G}_{\mu\nu}=\nabla^\mu 8\pi GT_{\mu\nu}$ ?

Comment: @Bob: see below, it's pure Riemann Geometry, you don't need Einstein's equation at all.  Note that, in vacuum, $T_{ab} =0\rightarrow R_{ab} = 0$, and the RHS of my answer vanishes.

Comment: yea, i saw the answer yesterday, and it makes sense. thanks. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\Box = \nabla^{2}$, then, remembering that $$\begin{align}
(1)\;&\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}\omega_{c} -\nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}\omega_{c} = R_{abc}{}^{d}\omega_{d}\\
(2)\;&\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}\phi = \nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}\phi\; ({\rm absence\,\,of\,\, torsion})
\end{align}$$

we can then see that:

$$\begin{align}
V_{a} &= \Box\nabla_{a}\phi - \nabla_{a}\Box\phi\\
&=g^{bc}\left(\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}\phi - \nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}\phi\right)\\
&=g^{bc}\left(\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}\phi - \left(\nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}\nabla_{c}\phi + R_{abc}{}^{d}\nabla_{d}\phi\right)\right)\\
&=g^{bc}\left(\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}\phi - \left(\nabla_{b}\nabla_{c}\nabla_{a}\phi + R_{abc}{}^{d}\nabla_{d}\phi\right)\right)\\
&=R_{a}{}^{d}\nabla_{d}\phi \neq 0
\end{align} $$

which is the identity given in Eq. 15 of your paper.